# render HTML from mySQL to display on a page Angular and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json, html

I am using Angular for front end, and node for back end. I am getting the data from a mySql db, where I have manually stored it in text format but with HTML tags on it i.e:

```
<ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

The data is currently in JSON format i.e:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sort_order": 0,
      "content_type": "main_message",
      "heading": "Welcome to our site ",
      "content": "<ul>
                      <li>item1</li>
                      <li>item2</li>
                      <li>item3</li>
                  </ul>",
      "page_name": "home",
      "author_id": "abhatti",
      "date_created": "2017-03-13T15:12:00.000Z",
      "date_modified": "2017-03-13T15:12:00.000Z",
      "modified_by": "abhatti"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sort_order": 0,
      "content_type": "main_body_content",
      "heading": "Announcements",
      "content": "",
      "page_name": "home",
      "author_id": "Robert",
      "date_created": "2016-12-31T17:00:00.000Z",
      "date_modified": "2017-03-11T07:08:00.000Z",
      "modified_by": "Danny"
    },
```

when I put the data in the table , I want the table to show the data in HTML format , but it shows in raw format with all the HTML tags visible on the page like this

```
<ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

but I want something like this

- item1
- item2
- item3

How can I convert the data properly so it is read by the browser as HTML? Right now it is put in as a string.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using now that's not working as expected?

Comment: data is in the format noted above , I am running  ng-repeat which goes through each object and displays it in a table . The problem is that it is not converting the HTML tags to display , it is taking the whole HTML as a string and puts " " around it . I can not put all the code here as there are a lot of files interconnected , but this is the best I can explain. I am basically trying to make a cms  where the user will be able to add or subtract lines from the content , while keeping the correct document formating.

Answer (score 0):

By default AngularJS (1.2+) will interpolate HTML as text.
This function is built into AngularJS to avoid XSS concerns, however there are times (such as in your case here) where you *may* actually want to render HTML in your template instead of displaying it as text.

To do so, take a look at AngularJS' [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) library. In your controller you can specify that you want to trust the data you retrieved from MySQL as HTML:

```
$scope.explicitlyTrustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div><span>Hello World!</span></div>');
```

In your template be sure to bind using `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="myCtrl.explicitlyTrustedHtml"></div>
</div>
```

If you *absolutely need* to, you can disable `$sce` for the entire application, however this is **highly** discouraged for security purposes. To do so inject `$sceProvider`, add the following line to your main module's configuration block:

```
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
```

Although the `$sce` library is helpful, my advice would be to find a better way to restructure your data in MySQL so that you're not asking it for HTML. If you're only ever reading the data -- you *might* be okay from a security perspective. However, if you're allowing users to POST HTML snippets from your AngularJS application and are persisting these snippets in MySQL, you're asking for XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks Ben for this wonderful piece of information , It worked just fine with $sce library . I really appreciate it !!!